# GDI is not rendering, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, gdi

I am trying to make a basic framework for graphics with GDI to make some minigames with.
But GDI is not rendering anything at all, I just get a black client area, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

The following code is inside a game loop that is running constantly:

```
//render double buffered with GDI
            HDC frontBuffer = GetDC(m_hMainWnd);

            HDC backBuffer;
            HBITMAP bitmap;
            HBITMAP oldBitmap;

            backBuffer = CreateCompatibleDC(frontBuffer);
            bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(frontBuffer, m_ClientWidth, m_ClientHeight);
            oldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(backBuffer, bitmap);

            GDI->StartDrawing(backBuffer, m_ClientWidth, m_ClientHeight); //this basically selects pens and brushes etc
            Render(dRenderTime); //here I render some stuff
            GDI->StopDrawing(backBuffer); //selects old pens and brushes back

         //blit backbuffer to frontbuffer
            BitBlt(frontBuffer, 0, 0, m_ClientWidth, m_ClientHeight, backBuffer, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            SelectObject(backBuffer, oldBitmap);
            DeleteObject(bitmap);
            DeleteDC(backBuffer);

            ReleaseDC(m_hMainWnd, frontBuffer);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
Sorry if it's some stupid mistake, I am not good at all with windows programming.

EDIT: additional code, as requested:

```
gdi.h

    #pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include "Macros.h"
#include "Transform.h"
#include "Text.h"

#define GDI gdi::getInstance()

class gdi
{
private:
  HPEN m_OldPen;
  HPEN m_Pen;
  HBRUSH m_OldBrush;
  HBRUSH m_Brush;
  HDC m_hdc;

  int m_DcWidth;
  int m_DcHeight;

  COLORREF m_Color;
  int m_LineWidth;

  DBlib::float3x3 m_Transform;

  gdi();

  void Transform(int& x_out, int& y_out, const DBlib::float2& p) const;
  void Transform_NDC_To_WC(int& x_out, int& y_out, const DBlib::float2& p) const;
  void Transfrom_WC_To_NDC(DBlib::float2& p_out, int x, int y) const;

public:
  ~gdi();

  static gdi* getInstance();

  void StartDrawing(HDC hdc, int dcwidth, int dcheight);
  void StopDrawing(HDC hdc);

  void SetColor(const DBlib::float3& col);
  void SetLineWidth(int width);

  void SetTransform(const DBlib::float3x3& transform);

  void DrawText(const DBlib::float2& p1, const std::tstring& s);
  void DrawLine(const DBlib::float2& p1, const DBlib::float2& p2);
  void DrawPolygon(const DBlib::float2* p, int size);
  void FillPolygon(const DBlib::float2* p, int size);
};
```

GDI.cpp

```
#include "gdi.h"

gdi* gdi::getInstance()
{
  static gdi instance;
  return &instance;
}

gdi::gdi()
{
  m_hdc = NULL;
  m_OldPen = NULL;
  m_OldBrush = NULL;
  m_LineWidth = 1;
  m_Color = RGB(0,0,0);
  m_DcWidth = -1;
  m_DcHeight = -1;
  m_Transform.set_identity();

  m_Pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID,1,RGB(0,0,0));
  m_Brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
}

gdi::~gdi()
{
    if(m_Pen) DeleteObject(m_Pen);
    if(m_Brush) DeleteObject(m_Brush);
}

void gdi::StartDrawing(HDC hdc, int dcwidth, int dcheight)
{
  m_hdc = hdc;
  m_DcWidth = dcwidth;
  m_DcHeight = dcheight;
  m_OldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, m_Pen);
  m_OldBrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, m_Brush);
}

void gdi::StopDrawing(HDC hdc)
{
  SelectObject(hdc, m_OldPen);
  SelectObject(hdc, m_OldBrush);

  m_hdc = NULL;
  m_DcWidth = -1;
  m_DcHeight = -1;
  m_OldPen = NULL;
  m_OldBrush = NULL;
}

void gdi::SetColor(const DBlib::float3& col)
{
    int r = static_cast<int>(DBlib::clamp(col.x*255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f));
    int g = static_cast<int>(DBlib::clamp(col.y*255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f));
    int b = static_cast<int>(DBlib::clamp(col.z*255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f));
    m_Color = RGB(r,g,b);

    SetTextColor(m_hdc, m_Color);

    if(m_Pen) DeleteObject(m_Pen);
    if(m_Brush) DeleteObject(m_Brush);
    m_Pen= CreatePen(PS_SOLID, m_LineWidth, m_Color);
    m_Brush= CreateSolidBrush(m_Color);
}

void gdi::SetLineWidth(int width)
{
    m_LineWidth = width;

    if(m_Pen) DeleteObject(m_Pen);
    m_Pen= CreatePen(PS_SOLID, m_LineWidth, m_Color);
}

void gdi::SetTransform(const DBlib::float3x3& transform)
{
    m_Transform = transform;
}

void gdi::Transform_NDC_To_WC(int& x_out, int& y_out, const DBlib::float2& p) const
{
    x_out = static_cast<int>((p.x+1.0f)*(static_cast<float>(m_DcWidth)/2.0f));
    y_out = m_DcHeight - static_cast<int>((p.y+1.0f)*(static_cast<float>(m_DcHeight)/2.0f));
}

void gdi::Transfrom_WC_To_NDC(DBlib::float2& p_out, int x, int y) const
{
    p_out.x = static_cast<float>(x)*2.0f/static_cast<float>(m_DcWidth) - 1.0f;
    p_out.y = -(static_cast<float>(y)*2.0f/static_cast<float>(m_DcHeight) - 1.0f);
}

void gdi::Transform(int& x_out, int& y_out, const DBlib::float2& p) const
{
    Transform_NDC_To_WC(x_out, y_out, p*m_Transform);
}

void gdi::DrawText(const DBlib::float2& pos, const std::tstring& s)
{
    int x,y;
    Transform(x,y,pos);
    TextOut(m_hdc, x, y, s.c_str(), (int)s.size());
}

void gdi::DrawLine(const DBlib::float2& p1, const DBlib::float2& p2)
{
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    Transform(x1,y1,p1);
    Transform(x2,y2,p2);

    MoveToEx(m_hdc, x1, y1, NULL);
    LineTo(m_hdc, x2, y2);
}

void gdi::DrawPolygon(const DBlib::float2* p, int size)
{
    int* x = new int[size];
    int* y = new int[size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        Transform(x[i],y[i],*(p+i));
    }
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        MoveToEx(m_hdc, x[i], y[i], NULL);
        LineTo(m_hdc, x[(i+1)%size], y[(i+1)%size]);
    }

    delete[] x;
    delete[] y;
}

void gdi::FillPolygon(const DBlib::float2* p, int size)
{
    int* x = new int[size];
    int* y = new int[size];
    POINT* pts = new POINT[size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        Transform(x[i],y[i],*(p+i));
        pts[i].x = static_cast<LONG>(x[i]);
        pts[i].y = static_cast<LONG>(y[i]);
    }

    Polygon(m_hdc, pts, size);

    delete[] x;
    delete[] y;
    delete[] pts;
}
```

App.cpp - Render method definition

```
void App::Render(float dTime)
{
    GDI->SetColor(DBlib::float3(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));
    GDI->SetLineWidth(50);
    GDI->DrawLine(DBlib::float2(-1.0f,-1.0f), DBlib::float2(1.0f,1.0f));
}
```

Comment: What's `GDI` in your code? I assume it's a class you made to wrap rendering logic but then you need to show that for us to help. Your code (after a quick glance) seems ok but you don't have the important pieces shown. Why is `Render` not part of `GDI`?

Comment: Another thing is - you shouldn't need to have the entire rendering logic in your game loop all the time - you only need to render the scene when something changes and then you only need to render the parts that changed. Rendering is very expensive and it'll use up a lot of your game's cycles if you render the scene all the time. Render your scene when you need to onto a bitmap and then just blit that bitmap onto the screen.

Comment: GDI is a singleton class that has some handy utility functions, such as DrawLine, SetColor, etc.
Render() is basically a method from App class(which is sort of starting point for the game), that uses GDI commands to render stuff.
I didn't add the code because I tried to keep it minimal and I thought my mistake was in the code I posted. I will add it now though.

Comment: That's normal for a game loop... Every frame something will have changed anyway, unless you're going for a specific type of game that doesn't have to redraw each frame

Comment: I am quite familiar with how to optimize rendering, I've made some games with DirectX before. But I just want to create something basic with GDI. Performance will not be an issue.

Comment: @xxbbcc Do you think this could have anything to do with WM_PAINT? Do I need to do something there? Or is that unnecessary when I draw like this?

Comment: Ys, WM_PAINT is where rendering in normal (non-DirectX programs) happen. You only get WM_PAINT when part of the window must be updated - if you want to redraw the whole scene, you need to invalidate the entire DC and then you'll get a WM_PAINT for the whole window. (My GDI is rusty, so my explanation could be sloppy but you get the picture. Give me some time, I'll dig up some of my old GDI projects.)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used to do GDI rendering (old production code translated from VB6). This is in response to `WM_PAINT` that is sent when either you (in your game loop) or Windows invalidates part of your window.

```
PAINTSTRUCT stPaintStruct;
HDC hPaintDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &stPaintStruct);

if (hPaintDC != HANDLE_NULL)
{
    // establish clipping rect using stPaintStruct.rcPaint

    if (!m_bRendering)
    {
        m_bRendering = TRUE;

        // Render() knows the output bitmap and all the content to render
        // and makes sure resources are allocated / discarded during
        // rendering.
        Render ();

        m_bRendering = FALSE;
    }

    EndPaint (hWnd, &stPaintStruct);
    return (TRUE);
}
```

You trigger a `WM_PAINT` by invalidating your window using [InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
InvalidateRect ( hWnd, NULL, FALSE );
```

Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about client drawing. Some of this is coming back to me slowly, thanks for the question. :) I haven't done GDI in years.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it like this and see if it works, give me some time :)

Comment: No problem - keep in mind, I translated this from my old VB6 code that I haven't seen in 5-6 years. :) Watch out for errors.

Comment: Nop, it's not working for me, I am calling InvalidateRect() inside the game loop, and used the old code inside WM_PAINT and added begin and end paint, but it's still the same black screen I get... hmm...

Comment: It's probably some small stupid error that is causing the entire thing to malfunction. I hate those errors! I'll look at it some more tomorrow, could've done this with DirectX faster, but I guess one of these days I have to learn GDI too, right? :p
Thanks for the time you took to help me though!

Comment: If you already know DirectX, you'd be far better off with it. I wouldn't use GDI for game programming - performance will be terrible. I spent a lot of time optimizing drawing of complex vector images in GDI but I assume your game loop is a lot tighter. GDI is good for business applications but games... meh, you'll torture yourself. :)

Comment: You're right, but I decided to stop focusing on graphics and actually make games... I want to focus on AI and physics for now, GDI will just serve as simple debug rendering :)

Comment: Why don't you set up something simple with an already existing graphics library for that? I'm sure you know some. Or use Flash and ActionScript - you'll simply have to move sprites around. You can also do bitmap drawing if you prefer and it's still a lot easier than GDI. (Flash is what I ended up for games - I got fed up with DirectX and all the other complex crap. I'm considering switching to JMonkey now since Flash seems to be going away.)

Comment: Flash and actionscript won't get me in the game industry :)
But the main reason is really because rendering performance will be no  issue at all, and I decided it would be a good occasion to work with GDI, in case I ever have to write some business application or whatnot :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd recommend starting with simple MSDN examples - they're easy to pick up. The only issue with GDI is the various objects that you need to select into the DC as you draw but it's really simple. If you have an otherwise complex game loop, it may be a nightmare to debug. The big pain with WM_PAINT is that you'll get a new one every time you switch over to the debugger. I hated debugging GDI problems. :)  Good luck with it, though.

Comment: Ok so I found my problem today. I was selecting a brush and a pen both at once, apparently it doesn't work like that. Everything is working fine now, in fact, it's doing even better outside WM_PAINT than inside.